# Relation between vertex connectivity and independent set

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory

> What is the relationship between vertex connectivity and independent set of a connected graph?

Suppose we have a graph on $20$ vertices which is connected.

If the independent set has cardinality $3$ what can we conclude about the vertex connectivity of the graph?

Another question :

Is there any algorithm to find the separating set of a graph?

Given a graph $G$ does there exist any command in SageMath or in any other software which can say the minimum separating set of a graph?

Comment: When you say "independent set", do you mean "maximal independent set"?

Comment: @M.Winter; not exactly ! I meant minimal independent set

Comment: Ok, it seems you do not mean "cardinality-wise minimal independent set", as this would be the empty set, which is independent and certainly minimal in size. What do you mean then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Addressing just this:

> "Given a graph  does there exist any command in SageMath or in any other software which can say the minimum separating set of a graph?"

This set is known as a [minimum vertex cut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_cut).

For the icosahedral graph $G$ below,
Mathematica's
`FindVertexCut[G]` yields `{3, 5, 6, 9, 10}`,
which surround and isolate vertex $1$.

---

[image: IcosaG]

---

Comment: Do you know of any such command or algorithm in SageMath as I dont have access to Mathematica(since it is not free)

Comment: @Math_Freak: see https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/graphs/sage/graphs/generic_graph.html#sage.graphs.generic_graph.GenericGraph.vertex_cut